# Not clear on reason for Error code 1004 on Index Match

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am struggling to understand why I get the error 1004 in the code below.. I have looked at similar questions but am not seeing the wood for the trees...

Image below shows the Local View - all looks good apart from the Updaterow value... The Valuetocheck field is set correct and does exist in the update table - I just need to find the row number.

I thought the error was to do with the updatesheet not being active but activating it didn't work.

[image: Screenshoot of Local values]

```vb
Sub Update_AmazonMatches()
    
    'Update Amazon Matches
    Dim lookupSheet As Worksheet
    Dim updateSheet As Worksheet
    Dim updaterow As Integer
    Dim valuetocheck As String
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim LastRowUpdate As Long
    Dim DateUpd As Date
    Dim lookupTbl As ListObject
    Dim updateTbl As ListObject
    
    Set lookupSheet = Worksheets("DATA - Barcode List")
    Set updateSheet = Worksheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    
    Set lookupTbl = lookupSheet.ListObjects("BCODE_Table")
    
    Set updateTbl = updateSheet.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    DateUpd = Date
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    'get the number of the last row with data for both tables
    
        LastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRowLookup = lookupSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    '=============================================================================================
    'Enure all data is showing in Barcode Table
        With lookupTbl
            If .ShowAutoFilter Then
                If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
            End If
         End With
    '=============================================================================================
    'For each record in the Barcode table - lookup Master Supplier Key in Supplier file and update Amazon Match and Date last match checked fields
            For l = 5 To LastRowLookup
             'look for the value in supplier key in Master Supplier file
             valuetocheck = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 3)
             
             updateSheet.Activate
            updaterow = WorksheetFunction.Index(lookupSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowUpdate), WorksheetFunction.Match(valuetocheck, updateSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowUpdate), "No Match"))
    
          'if found a match, copy Amazon Match and Date last match checked fieldsand proceed to the next value- I KNOW THESE REFERENCES ARE WRONG BUT ONCE I GET CELL VALUE FROM INDEX MATCH I WILL CHANGE THEM
                
                If updateSheet.Cells(updaterow, 3) = valuetocheck Then
                    updateSheet.Cells(updaterow, 18).Value = DateUpd
                    updateSheet.Cells(updaterow, 17).Value = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 17)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next l
    '=============================================================================================
        MsgBox "Amazon Match Update Completed.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
         wsf.Calculate
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add this line of code before your 'problem' line `Debug.Print "LastRowUpdate = " & LastRowUpdate & ", valuetocheck = '" & valuetocheck & "'"` ... do you have the values you would expect?

Comment: Also, `LastRowLookup` is not declared ... unlikely to be related to your immediate problem but including `Option Explicit` and declaring all your variables will make your code more robust.

Comment: If Match function is the same as in PC the third parameter is match_type can be -1,0,1

Comment: `lookupSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowUpdate` looks wrong, should be `lookupSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowLookup` perhaps.

Comment: all values are as expected and thanks @Blackcat I did have it as 0 originally - have set to 0 and still errors... I think it is to do with the  fact there are 2 sheets involved but I thought by adding the reference infront of the range that would set the sheet values..or have i got the syntax on that wrong?

Comment: Ok i changed the match to include the sheet name..Match(valuetocheck, Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File").Range("A2:A" & LastRowUpdate)... this gets me past the 1004 error but I expect a match to be found and a value in updaterow . but it is returning a 0

Comment: That is updatesheet and not lookupsheet. If there is no match its results an 1004 error

Comment: @blackcat  i am looking for VALUETOCHECK in the MASTER - Supplier File sheet... just spotted I had wrong sheet on the Index but still get a 0 in the UpdateRow - it should find a match...  updaterow = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File").Range("A2:A" & LastRowUpdate), WorksheetFunction.Match(valuetocheck, Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File").Range("A2:A" & LastRowUpdate), 0))

Comment: am going to split the index and match to two statements - see if that makes anything clearer

Comment: Why you need INDEX ? MATCH give the row number.

Comment: valuetocheck also from lookupsheet which is `"DATA - Barcode List"`

Comment: I have a table in "DATA - Barcode List" which has a Supplier Key in col a (Valuetocheck) and a value in column d. I want to lookup Valuetocheck in a table in sheet "MASTER - Supplier File" which gas Supplier key as colulum a - if I find a match I want to update column q with value from colum d on "DATA - Barcode List" and column p with todays date - so i need the row number fro the update... hope that makes sense!

Comment: valuetocheck = lookupSheet.Cells(l, 3) This assign for the first, cell `C5` in `"DATA - Barcode List"` not D5

Comment: Correct - it should the do the index/match and updated then move to value in C6 repeat till end of data in C

Comment: The Index function returns the content of the cell. If you want the actual row number than after the expression add `.Row`

Comment: @Blackcat that was it! I almost had it just needed the .ROW... it hasn't updated as i thought but I can look at that now - it is getting past the index/Match issue! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Match` gives the row that matches from which you can put the column D value.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Update_AmazonMatches()
    
    'Update Amazon Matches
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsBCODE As Worksheet, wsMSF As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, LastRowMSF As Long, LastRowBCODE As Long
    Dim valuetocheck As String, r As Variant
    Dim tblBCODE As ListObject, tblMSF As ListObject
    Dim rngBCODE As Range, rngMSF As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsBCODE = wb.Sheets("DATA - Barcode List")
    With wsBCODE
        Set tblBCODE = .ListObjects("BCODE_Table")
        LastRowBCODE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngBCODE = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowBCODE)
    End With
    
    Set wsMSF = wb.Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    With wsMSF
        Set tblMSF = .ListObjects("MSF_Table")
        LastRowMSF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngMSF = .Range("A1:A" & LastRowMSF)
    End With
    
    'Enure all data is showing in Barcode Table
    With tblBCODE
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
    
    ' For each record in the Barcode table -
    ' lookup Master Supplier Key in Supplier file and
    ' update Amazon Match and Date last match checked fields
    wsMSF.Unprotect
    With wsBCODE
        For i = 5 To LastRowBCODE
            'look for the value in supplier key in Master Supplier file
            valuetocheck = .Cells(i, "A")
            r = Application.Match(valuetocheck, rngMSF, 0)
            If IsError(r) Then
                If vbNo = MsgBox(valuetocheck & " not found in " & rngMSF.Address(, , , True) & _
                          " Continue ?", vbYesNo) Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                ' if found a match, copy Amazon Match and Date last match checked fields
                ' and proceed to the next value
                ' I KNOW THESE REFERENCES ARE WRONG BUT
                ' ONCE I GET CELL VALUE FROM INDEX MATCH I WILL CHANGE THEM
                wsMSF.Cells(r, 17).Value = .Cells(i, "D")
                wsMSF.Cells(r, 18).Value = Date
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    wsMSF.Protect
   
    MsgBox "Amazon Match Update Completed.", vbInformation, "PROC_TITLE"
    'wsf.Calculate
        
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
        
End Sub
```